# Python Pandas Relation Between Distance and Weekday Column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataset which has distance and weekday column.
Distance is double value, weekday is string.(Monday,Tuesday...)

How do i show the relation between distance and weekday ? I need to check that distances are increasing in weekends or not.

some part of the data:

[image]

never mind time_of_day column

```
 distance weekday
    1.498991 Monday
    5.122769 Thursday
    1.492705 Friday
    1.972825 Monday
    2.517838 Monday
    1.648552 Saturday
    2.503511 Thursday
    1.671742 Friday
    3.974399 Friday
    7.616923 Wednesday
```

Comment: Could you share some of your data and code you've tried so far?

Comment: i added some part of the data

Comment: Could you please share the data as text instead of screenshots? The first thing any potential answerer will want to do is copy-paste the data into their working environment. Posting images presents an unnecessary barrier against quick experimentation and answering

Comment: In the meantime, try something like `df.groupby('weekday')['distance'].agg(['mean', 'std'])`, and for visualization, look into `df.boxplot()`

Comment: I would binarize if it is a weekday or a weekend as a separate column and then you could just calculate the correlation, or the mean values for weekdays and weekends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you want to determine the relationship between Weekdays and Weekends, you should split them up into two groups. This can be achieved by assigning a 0 to Weekdays and 1 to Weekends.

To get a more reliable result you need a greater sample size to determine if a significant relationship exists between Weekends and Weekdays.

Once you get a greater dataset you can calculate the mean and correlation using the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

d = ({             
   'Day' : ['Monday','Thursday','Friday','Monday','Monday','Saturday','Thursday','Friday','Friday','Wednesday'],                                                                      
   'Distance' : [1.498991,5.122769,1.492705,1.972825,2.517838,1.648552,2.503511,1.671742,3.974399,7.616923],                                                               
   'Group' : [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],                                                                              
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#The average distance for Weekdays
Weekday = df.loc[df['Day'] == 0]
Weekday_mean = Weekday['Distance'].mean()

#The average distance for Weekends
Weekend = df.loc[df['Day'] == 1]
Weekend_mean = Weekend['Distance'].mean()

#Correlation between Weekends and Weekdays
corr = (numpy.corrcoef(df['Distance'],df['Day']))

print(corr)

[[ 1.         -0.23640194]
 [-0.23640194  1.        ]]
```

It's a negative relationship at the moment because you only have one value for a weekend.